# Show convergence by using comparison test $\sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am having problems with proving that $$\sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$$ converges by using the comparison test. I have shown that it converges by finding its sum. It's a telescoping sum and its sum is equal to 1. I have also tried to show that it converges by saying that

$$\sum_{n \geq 2}\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\approx \sum_{n \geq 2}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

and since $\sum_{n \geq 2} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, so does the original series.

I am not sure if the above is correct I would appreciate some comments and hints on how I can show convergence by using the comparison test.

Best regards

Husky

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{n(n-1)} \le \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$.

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't think of that one. So since $\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$ is always less than or equal to the original series and since it converges, that means that the original series converges too. Great! Thank you.

Comment: My problem in general with these type of exercises is that I don't really know which series to compare them too. I mean I know I have to compare them to series I know converge or diverge in order to be able to make a conclusion. The problem is though that I don't think I know enough series. For example now you compared it to the series $\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$. But I had to use wolfram to find out that it converges, since the ratio and root tests are inconclusive.

Comment: In order to show that it converges the comparison test is used, but again how can I use this test to show that $\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$ converges? And sorry about all the text. I am just a bit frustrated over not seeing the result myself.

Comment: It's far from trivial see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem. In fact, about the easiest way just to prove convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ is to compare it with $\sum \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$, which converges as you have proved by the telescoping argument $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: Ah I see! So instead of proving that $\sum \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$ converges you just prove that that $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges by using the comparison test. Thanks for the link and help :)

Comment: $\sum \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$ is just a reindexing of $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ (maybe with a few leading terms added or omitted). Reindexing and adding or omitting leading terms doesn't affect convergence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't use things like $\approx$ unless you really know what you are doing. Instead, you could bound the sum below and above as follows:

$0 \le \sum_{n=2}^k \frac{1}{n(n-1)} \le \sum_{n=2}^k \frac{1}{(n-1)^2} < \infty$.

Thus the partial sums of the series you want are monotonically increasing and bounded above. Therefore the series converges.

Comment: Ah okay thank you very much :) I will be careful with $\approx$ from now on! How would you now show that $\sum \frac{1}{(n-1)^2}$ converges? The ratio and root test are inconclusive, so I know I have to use the comparison test. My problem though is that I don't have enough practice, so I don't know how I know I have compared it to the right series.

Comment: @Husky653: In fact one shows that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ converges by bounding it above by $1 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k-1)}$, for which you can easily find the partial sums and hence the limit.

Comment: @Husky653: Oh I just noticed *Rob Arthan* has said the same thing in an earlier comment.

Comment: In fact, the series on the right-hand side converges to $\pi^2/6$.

Comment: "You shouldn't use things like ≈ unless you really know what you are doing" I think you shouldn't use it formally, but informally I think it's very good. No?

Comment: @Ovi: No, because it's prone to error even if you try to keep the rigorous version in mind. It's always better to have the asymptotic bounds explicit. In this particular case, it's even wrong; the two sums are definitely not $≈$ (approximately equal). I personally use "$x≈y$" only in a limiting context, to mean "$x,y$ eventually gets and remains arbitrarily close (possibly equal)", such as in "$\sin(x)/x ≈ 0$ as $x→∞$". Without a limiting context, "$\approx$" is meaningless.